# unable to run "composer update"

Tags: php, composer-php

When I try to run "composer update" I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ReflectionParameter::getType() in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer
.phar/src/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php on line 110
```

`php -v` tells me that I'm running 5.5.15 and `composer --version` tells me the following:

```
Composer version 1.0-dev (974fb4ac66c427b87f3cfa29e1320cd97f182b9d) 2016-01-16 17:45:40
```

The PHP version should be perfectly acceptable since Composer says it minimally requires version is 5.3.3 per https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#system-requirements

Aany ideas?

Comment: It seems like your Composer install has a missing method, which is weird. Try removing and reinstalling Composer and see if that works or the error still persists.

Comment: @AchrafAlmouloudi - that worked - thanks!